# Changing httpreq to axios' post

Tags: node.js, axios

I'm having issues with authentication when I change from httpreq to axios' post. I need to use multipart/form-data. For some reason it isn't working in axios, but it is in httpreq. What am I missing?

httpreq:

```
 postType1ToServer: function(request, callback) {
    var options = {
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
        Connection: 'keep-alive',
        Authorization: request.type1msg
      },
      agent: keepaliveAgent
    };
return httpreq[request.method](request.options.url, options);
```

versus axios

```
postType1ToServer: function(request, callback) {
    var options = {
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
        Connection: 'keep-alive',
        Authorization: request.type1msg
      },
      httpAgent: new http.Agent({ keepAlive: true })
    };

    return axios
      .post(request.options.url,  options)
      .then(function(response) {
        console.log(response);
      })
      .catch(function(response) {
        console.log(response);
      });
```

Comment: Where is your payload for axios? `axios.post(endpoint, payload, options)`. You need to put your `FormData` object as that second parameter.

Answer (score 0):

See [the documentation](https://github.com/axios/axios#axiosposturl-data-config):

> ```
> axios.post(url[, data[, config]])
> ```

You've put the config where the data is supposed to be, and missed the data out entirely.

Answer (score -1):

You can try to remove backslash form URL at end of it

Comment: What backslash?

Comment: On SO you should answer with complete answers with examples or explanation (when applicable)